# Django field that is a hybrid of text file upload and/or text box

Tags: python, django, forms, django-admin

I'm trying to see if this is possible: a `Field` object that is rendered as both a file upload prompt as well as a text box. Since my app deals with SSL certificates and keys, it makes sense to allow the user to either upload a key/cert file, or paste the key/cert in directly.

Regardless of the method of input chosen, the data would be stored as a `text` column in the backing database. This would purely be for convenience's sake.

Answer (score 0):

> Regardless of the method of input chosen, the data would be stored as
>   a text column in the backing database.

In that case, I would use a regular `CharField`. It just makes more sense.

In the form, use 2 not required fields instead: `key_text` and `key_file`. Overwrite `clean()` to make at least one required. Then overwrite `save(...)`.